# Ошибка в Documentum при выполнении метода dm_event_sender

Tags: java, email

При попытке отправки уведомления об изменении статуса документа пользователям, состоящим в определенной группе, происходит ошибка.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с данным продуктом (Documentum)? В какую сторону копать?

> `Thu Nov 18 09:14:23 2021 187694: 25555[25555] HTTP_POST TRACE LAUNCH: user: user, session id: 12312312, host:test, port:9580, path:/DmMail/servlet/DoMail, arguments:-launch_async T -docbase_name "test" -due_date "none" -event_name "dm_startedworkitem" -message_text "Test" -object_name "dormant" -package_id 4a03aca98376a64c -planned_start_date "none" -task_priority 5 -router_id 4d03aca98049b117 -router_name "ROUTER_NAME" -sender_name "user" -supervisor_name "USER" -task_name "TASK_NAME" -task_number "4" -recipient_login_name "GROUP" -recipient_name " " -platform undefined -mail_user_name "user" -stamp 1b03aca981365d36 -date_sent "11/18/2021 9:14:22 AM" -link_cnt 0 -package_type "manual" -content_type " " -content_size 0 -dos_extension " " -web_server "test|80" -web_server_type "/type" -temp_file_name "/var/tmp/jaakRay6X" -mail_script ./dm_mailwrapper.sh -bulk_mail_file "/var/tmp/iaajRay6X" -smtp_server "mysmtpserver.com" -login_ticket "DM_TICKET=12312312" -recipient_login_domain " " -trace_file /documentum/shared_60sp1/logs/mail_trace.log -trace_level 0`
>
> `Thu Nov 18 09:14:23 2021 188553: 25555[25555] HTTP_POST TRACE LAUNCH: post: successful, user: user, session id: 0103aca98260fdfc, app_server_name: do_mail`
> `Thu Nov 18 09:14:23 2021 598154: 25162[25162] TRACE LAUNCH: ./dmbasic -f./dm_event_sender.ebs -eMail  -- "user" "none" "dm_startedworkitem" "Message" "dormant" "4a03aca98376a64c" "none" "5" "4d03aca98049b117" "EVENT" "user" "USER" "Select" "4" "GROUP" " " "undefined" "user" "1b03aca981365d36" "11/18/2021 9:14:22 AM" "0" "manual" " " "0" " " "test|80" "/type" "/var/tmp/jaakRay6X" "./dm_mailwrapper.sh" "/var/tmp/iaajRay6X" "mysmtpserver.com"`
>
> `dmExec::ForkLaunch() system(./dmbasic -f./dm_event_sender.ebs -eMail  -- "user" "none" "dm_startedworkitem" "Message" "dormant" "4a03aca98376a64c" "none" "5" "4d03aca98049b117" "EVENT" "user" "USER" "Select" "4" "GROUP" " " "undefined" "user" "1b03aca981365d36" "11/18/2021 9:14:22 AM" "0" "manual" " " "0" " " "test|80" "/type" "/var/tmp/jaakRay6X" "./dm_mailwrapper.sh" "/var/tmp/iaajRay6X" "mysmtpserver.com")`
>
> `dmExec::ForkLaunch() returns: 65280, errno: 9`
>
> `dmExec::ForkLaunch() returning value: 255`

Comment: как будто из внутренной jira скопировали багу, но без контекста тут сложно сказать что пошло не так.

Comment: Оказывается, что у нас используется dm_event_template_sender, а в случае ошибки в его работе вызывается дефолтный dm_event_sender. И получается, что по какой-то причине dm_event_template_sender не может найти темплейт сообщения для заданного процесса.

Comment: И возникает вопрос где описывается связь между процессом и темплейтом.

Comment: без кода тут можно только на кофейней гуще гадать.